# How to check observableArray change

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am using knockout_2.0.js. I have an observableArray on which i set subscribe. Like :

```
 var Items = ko.observableArray();


 Items.subscribe(function(newValue){

  //I want to check here whether the item is Added or Deleted from the array

 });
```

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know if something was added or removed you could easily track that with a variable on the outer scope.

```
var items = ko.observableArray();

var itemLen = items.length;

items.subscribe(function (newValue) {

    //I want to check here whether the item is Added or Deleted from the array
    if (itemLen > items.length) {
        // Item removed
    } else if (itemLen < items.length) {
        // item added
    } else {
        // something else was modified
    }
    itemLen = items.length;
});
```

Comment: Would this work in all cases where something was added *and* removed?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code,this may help.

```
var Items = ko.observableArray();
var ItemsLength = ko.observableArray();

this.ItemsLength = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
    return this.Items().length;
    }
});

this.ItemsLength.subscribe(function(newValue){

  //you will get control over here whether the
       item is Added or Deleted from the array

});
```